# Compact Operator Improves Regularity in Function Spaces

Tags: compact-operators, function-spaces

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded domain, and let $T:L^2(\Lambda)\to L^2(\Lambda)$ be a compact operator. Can we say anything about the regularity of $Tf$, $f\in L^2(\Lambda)$? Does a compact operator improve the regularity of the function $f$ in this case? What about the case where $T$ is trace-class or Hilbert-Schmidt?

Thank you very much!
Luke

Comment: What kind of regularity are you looking for? Smoothness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_0$ is a fixed function in $L^{2}$ then $Tf=\langle f , f_0 \rangle f_0$ is compact, of trace class and Hilbert-Shmidt. $Tf$ does not have any smoothness property if $f_0$ does not have such a  property except when $Tf=0$ (or $\langle f , f_0 \rangle=0$).

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind (assuming OP intended smoothness) and a good concrete example would be a Haar wavelet. The Haar functions make an orthonormal basis and they're very far from smooth.

Comment: Thanks for that example! It shows that $Tf$ is in general "as bad as" $f$ itself.